# Dynamically creating a specific number of input form elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've read many blogs and posts on dynamically adding fieldsets, but they all give a very complicated answer. What I require is not that complicated.

My HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
<a href="#" id="filldetails">Fill Details</a>
```

So, a user will enter an integer value (I'm checking the validation using javascript) in the `input` field. And on clicking the `Fill Details` link, corresponding number of input fields will appear for him to enter. I want to achieve this using javascript.

I'm not a pro in javascript. I was thinking how can I retrieve the integer filled in by the user in `input` field through the link and displaying corresponding number of input fields.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You could use an `onclick` event handler in order to get the input value for the text field. Make sure you give the field an unique `id` attribute so you can refer to it safely through `document.getElementById()`:

If you want to dynamically add elements, you should have a container where to place them. For instance, a `<div id="container">`. Create new elements by means of `document.createElement()`, and use `appendChild()` to append each of them to the container. You might be interested in outputting a meaningful `name` attribute (e.g. `name="member"+i` for each of the dynamically generated `<input>`s if they are to be submitted in a form.

Notice you could also create `<br/>` elements with `document.createElement('br')`. If you want to just output some text, you can use `document.createTextNode()` instead.

Also, if you want to clear the container every time it is about to be populated, you could use `hasChildNodes()` and `removeChild()` together.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
            // Generate a dynamic number of inputs
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            // Get the element where the inputs will be added to
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Remove every children it had before
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                // Append a node with a random text
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i+1)));
                // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "member" + i;
                container.appendChild(input);
                // Append a line break 
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
    <div id="container"/>
</body>
</html>
```

See a working sample in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t656N/1/).

Comment: I followed your advice. But when I click on, the browser console shows this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined `

Comment: The answer so much helpful. And how can I add a CSS class to the field

Comment: @Pravin Glad it helped, see [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/507138/851811). Basically use `input.className += ' someCSSClass';`

Comment: When I submit the form, the new fields generated dynamically are not submitted like the other fields that were part of the original HTML. They show up visually and I can inspect them but they don't submit. Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: @circle1 Make sure the dynamically generated elements do have a unique  `name` attribute. Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Comment: @Xavi López I did check that first thing and they do have a valid and unique name attribute. If I take the HTML appended by the javaScript and have it load as part of the original HTML, they work fine, but when they are added on the fly by JS they won't submit.

Comment: I just created small project to test whether dynamically added input with name will get submitted using C# MVC. It worked fine. Not sure what framework you were using, but perhaps your model was missing property with the same name as "name" attribute?

Comment: @AGrush well, it still does for me. What exactly do you find that is not working?

Comment: sorry it does figured it out thanks, had to put a number in the input

Answer (score 53):

Try this JQuery code to dynamically include form, field, and delete/remove behavior:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $(".container1");
    var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
        } else {
            alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
    <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; 
      <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
    </button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but in my case any pressing enter in a text field in this form will lead to the 'Add New Field' button's function being fired, which is probably unwanted behavior...

Comment: `<button type="button" ...>` and the problem is solved.

Comment: Hello! When I go to save the data of the dynamic inputs, how do I recover them all?

Comment: Good answer. plus+. BUT... vanilla javascript ?? Some people dislike adding libraries.

Comment: @M. Lak let's suppose we increase the input element by `1` on each `click` event and these `fields` values are submitted with `form` how can we retrieve each `input` field `values` 
can you please update the answer so that each `input` field will have dynamic (unique) `id` or `name` attr

Comment: Also how can we **validate** such `form` using `jquery`