# form submit don't recognize dynamically added input (using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, django-templates

I have html code with form:

```
<tr>
<form action="/some_action/" method="POST" id="send_form" class="test-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
        </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn-add btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
                    add <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"/>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="courier-date-from-data">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="courier-date-to-data">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="start-km-data">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="end-km-data">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-options btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li type="submit" class="btn-options-save"><a onclick="">save</a></li>
                <li class="btn-options-cancel"><a onclick="">cancel</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </form>
```

and input templates on the bottom:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control  start-km-template" style="display: none;" name="" id="">
<input type="number" class="form-control  end-km-template" style="display: none;" name="" id="">
```

JavaScript:

```
var selector2 = "start-km-0";
$( ".start-km-template" )
                .clone()
                .removeClass("start-km-template")
                .css("display","block")
                .addClass(selector2)
                .attr("id", selector2)
                .attr("name", selector2)
                .appendTo(".start-km-data");
```

When I want to submit request (using just input with type="submit"), form don't recognize new input field in form tag.
How to fix this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding input elements dynamically to form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form)

Comment: How do you submit your form data? With JavaScript or JQuery? I don't see any submit button in you code. Probably, if you add submit event before adding elements, you need to attach a handler to and event again or do it in other more right way.

Comment: It's Django, I've just `type="submit"` in my input

Comment: I see that in your templates inputs don't have name (`<input ... name="">`). Maybe because of it form doesn't see them?

Comment: Check with devtools if inputs have name

Comment: inputs have ids and names before I click button.

Comment: @Leena I try to do this in that way, and nothing change... It is a function to refresh DOM ?