# Creating multiple objects of same model with a single form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to create several instances of same model form a single form. And more importantly, the number of instances aren't known before form rendering.

I've seen several tutorials of this kind, but unfortunately those didn't suit my need. I've seen Ryan bate's nested form tutorial. But I'm not creating nested form. I've also seen some tutorials, which do create multiple objects, but the number of object's are all known in those cases. One of the tutorial is here - http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=717

User will click a button and a new set of fields for a new object will be inserted just like the nested form demo from ryanb.

Here is a mockup of what I want. It's basically a very small form fit into a single line.

[image]

Comment: How will it be decided how many objects you need to create? Does the user decide? If you have a mockup of the UI that'd be helpful.

Comment: User will decide dynamically, they add as many as they wish

Comment: How will they "add as many as they wish"? Do they click a button to add more fields or something?

Comment: Yes, they will click a button.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you need [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) it allows to add form fields

Comment: I'll check and give feedback on answer

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you may need to reach beyond Rails views and utilize javascript to dynamically render more "partials" when the user decides to add more fields. Something like this: [Adding input elements dynamically to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form)

If you want to keep your view rendering logic in rails, you could make an AJAX request to your application, have it return just a partial's worth of html back, and insert the response html into your dom.