# Function that call input type text - Javascript / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

i'm creating a form page where i 'ill put some inputs to my customers fill it.

but , every time i must write for example >

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantidade" required max="900" />
```

for example , but i see a friend that was using javascript function to call theses input , so when he want insert a input like this , he just call on your index.page .

someone could help ?

i have tryed this .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function add() {
    document.getElementById("inputnumber").innerHTML = '<input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantidade" required max="900" />';
  }
</script>
```

with this index.page

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group" id="inputnumber">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Make sure the *add* function is called after the *inputnumber* element is loaded. Also, replacing the value of the *innerHTML* property will remove all content and replace it with elements created from the newly assigned markup. Also, your markup is invalid.

Comment: You have no `</div>` to match `<div id="inputnumber">`

Comment: Your function should work. How are you calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy, u need this function, look:

```
function callInput(a,b,c) {
    var x = document.createElement('input');
    x.className = 'form-control';
    x.type = b;
    x.name = c;
    a.appendChild(x);
}
```

How to use, look:

```
callInput(parentElemen,'type','name');
```

Example:

```
callInput(document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0],'submit','quantidade');
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

yes this will work but you should place your function call after declaring your html element you're using. for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function add()
 {
document.getElementById("inputnumber").innerHTML = '<input type="number"      class="form-control" name="quantidade" required max="900" />';
}
</script>
<div id="inputnumber"></div>
<script>
    add()
</script>
```

As you might notice the function call is placed after the "inputnumber" dev

```
<div id="inputnumber"></div>
```

Comment: The function definition doesn't have to be after the element, only the call to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here simple example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add(){
        document.getElementById("inputnumber").innerHTML = '<input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantidade" required max="900"/>';
    }
</script>
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group" id="inputnumber">
    </div>
    <button onclick="add();">Add +</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

**Note:** If you want to add only one input element. Run this code and you will get it.

For **multiple element** on your form, take a look at

[Dynamically add form element using Javascript-Simple one](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/)
[Append Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form) 
[Good and Simple: Add Input Fields Dynamically to Form Using JavaScript](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2010/02/add-input-fields-dynamically-to-form-using-javascript.html)