# Dynamically add field using js in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to dynamically add more input fields in my laravel bootstrap 3 app. But when I click add then nothing happens even if I have jquery etc in my project:

head of index:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

footer:

```
 <script src="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Code in file:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
       <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
              <div class="input-group-btn"> 
              <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button">
                 Add
              </button>
              </div>
    </div>
 </div>


          <script type="text/javascript">

              $(document).ready(function() {

            //here first get the contents of the div with name class copy-fields and add it to after "after-add-more" div class.
                $(".add-more").click(function(){ 
                    var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
                    $(".after-add-more").after(html);
                });
          //here it will remove the current value of the remove button which has been pressed
                $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
                    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
                });

              });

          </script>
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form

Comment: Where is the `<div class="copy-fields">...</div>` defined?