# How do you extract variables from javascript for html web form

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi-bin

Okay I have seen script which I got from this site [Adding input elements dynamically to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form)
I have made some slight changes to it. The objective of the script is to ask a user for an input and then supply them with number of fields. Assume the person puts in 3. I would then want to capture those three inputs as a list and export them to python. I am currently using cgi-bin and python. Those are parameters I have to work with.

1. How can I pull the elements from the web form using that script
2. Once I activate the addfileds function. I am unable to see fields in the form below it. I would like to have more than one dynamic fields.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: And post your code...