# Update field type using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am running a marketplce using Sharetribe Go which only allows for limited custom script (their hosted version so no access to code)

I have an input field which is set to 'text' but want to change this to a 'textarea' field. I can see that they use the following for a text area:

`<textarea maxlength="5000" class="listing_description_textarea" name="custom_fields[143742]" id="custom_fields_143742" style="overflow: hidden visible; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal;"></textarea>`

Is there any script I can write to convert my custom field (name="custom_fields[143742]") to a textarea field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding input elements dynamically to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form)

Comment: Remove one field, add another.