# jquery delete parent doesnt work on the whole Line! What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, symfony

I used the last answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form) to Add Lines to my Poll which i am creating in Symfony but the string i am appending is a bit longer then the one in the answer

`('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>')`

Mine looks like that (with twig, u don't have to understand everything in there, important is only the line `<div><a href="#" <class="delete">Delete</a></div>'` at the bottom):

```
'<div class="ul-div"><ul class="lst-none">\n' +
'    <li>\n' +
'        {% for Field in lineArray %}\n' +
'            <div class="{% if loop.first %}lineFieldFirst{% else %}lineField{% endif %}">\n' +
'                {% if Field.getType() == "choice" %}\n' +
'                    <select name="field_choice_{{ Field.getId() }}[]" id="field_choice_{{ Field.getId() }}">\n' +
'                        {% for Fieldvalue in Field.getFieldvaluesBySO() %}\n' +
'                            <option value="{{ Fieldvalue.getValue() }}">{{ Fieldvalue.getTranslationName(app.request.getLocale()) }}</option>\n' +
'                        {% endfor %}\n' +
'                    </select>\n' +
'                {% elseif Field.getType() == "checkbox" %}\n' +
'                    <label for="field_checkbox_{{ Field.getId() }}">{{ Field.getTranslationName(app.request.getLocale()) }}</label>\n' +
'                    <input type="checkbox" id="field_checkbox_{{ Field.getId() }}" name="field_checkbox_{{ Field.getId() }}[]">\n' +
'                {% elseif Field.getType() == "date" %}\n' +
'                    <label for="field_date_{{ Field.getId() }}">{{ Field.getTranslationName(app.request.getLocale()) }}</label>\n' +
'                    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="field_date_{{ Field.getId() }}" name="field_date_{{ Field.getId() }}[]">\n' +
'                {% elseif Field.getType() == "number" %}\n' +
'                    <input type="number" id="field_number_{{ Field.getId() }}" name="field_number_{{ Field.getId() }}[]" min="0" value="0" required>\n' +
'                {% elseif Field.getType() == "text" %}\n' +
'                    <label for="field_text_{{ Field.getId() }}">{{ Field.getTranslationName(app.request.getLocale()) }}</label>\n' +
'                    <input type="text" id="field_text_{{ Field.getId() }}" name="field_text_{{ Field.getId() }}[]">\n' +
'                {% endif %}\n' +
'            </div>\n' +
'        {% endfor %}\n' +
'        <div><a href="#" <class="delete">Delete</a></div>' +
'    </li>\n' +
'</ul></div>'
```

Clearly the function

```
$(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
})
```

does not work anymore because it only deletes the div around the <a> tags, but even when i:

- remove the div around that
- use `parent('div.ul-div')`
- use `parent('ul')`
- use `parent('div').parent('div')`

The Button doesn't delete the whole Line!
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: is this `<` a typo here `<class="..` ?

Comment: try with ` $(this).closest('div').remove();`

Comment: closest works, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Twig so, unless it's part of Twig, you seems to have a typo in your `<div><a href="#" <class="delete">Delete</a></div>` before the word `class` there is a `<` sign you should remove.

Also, Try using `closest()` instead of `parent()` since the last one only travels a single level up. `closest()` will get the first element matched no matter how many levels up, so you could even remove the `<div class="ul-div">` with it.

Comment: Consider voting to close these type of questions next time since they are consider off-topic because the problem was caused by a typo