# Form with get method isn't working (url and jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, get

I'm using the next JavaScript and Jquery code for to insert inputs in the html DOM:

```
function insertInput(elemento) {
    $(elemento).html("<input  type='text' id='"+elemento.slice(1)+"' name='"+elemento.slice(1)+"'>")
}
```

the parameter *elemento* is an **id** and **name** for the input to be generated, and the form I used is the following:

```
<form method="get">
    <div id="inputs">
        ... input insertion
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Aceptar</button>
</form>
```

and the above code, generates this

```
<form method="get">
    <div id="inputs">
        //example id and name
        <input type="text" id="calorias1" name="calorias1">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Aceptar</button>
</form>
```

So far, everything works as it should, but, when I press the submit button, the url must be de following:

*index.html?calorias1=anyvalue*

instead of that:

*index.html?*

I don't know why that happens

Comment: Does it work if you use <input type=submit> instead of a button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding input elements dynamically to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form) (You need to create the inputs programmatically using `document.createElement()` or the jquery equivalent and append them inside the form. Merely changing the innerHTML doesn't register the new input with the form object.)

Comment: @AllanWind placing <input type=submit> does not work either :c. But, the button works when I put the input field in manually. thanks anyway, any help is always welcome :).

Comment: @pilchard I'll try it, and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Uh guys, for some reason the browser misinterpreted `<form>` tags, put internal elements (`<div>` and `<input>`) outside of `<form>` tags, I just deleted `<form>` tags in my code editor, I put'em back and it worked ( was a rare bug I had never seen that ). thank you both very much, I learned something new (`document.createElement()`).