# Express Validator - dynamic form field validation

Tags: node.js, express, validation, express-validator

```
<input name="foo[]" ... >
```

I've used these before, but I'm wondering what it is called and results in various Google results only call it an "array" but I want to validate multiple fields in Express API which have dynamically added from the frontend side.
Frontend HTML:

```
<form>
    <div id="persons">
        <div data-col="1">
            <title>Person 1:</title>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input name="first_name[]">

            <label>Last name</label>
            <input name="last_name[]">

            <label>Email</label>
            <input name="email[]">
        </div>
        <div data-col="2">

            <title>Person 2:</title>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input name="first_name[]">

            <label>Last name</label>
            <input name="last_name[]">

            <label>Email</label>
            <input name="email[]">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button">Add new person</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In Express API, I am using [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) to validate my fields. I want to validate request object on Express API where all fields must have equal number of elements on each array (first_name,last_name,email, etc..), and also each array have a different type of datatype like email should be validated as Email and other should be as String.
Request Object on Backend:

```
{
    "first_name[]": [
        "foo1",
        "foo2",
    ],
    "last_name[]": [
        "foo1",
        "foo2",
    ],
    "email[]": [
        "foo1",
        "foo2",
    ]
}
```

Comment:  is there any reason to do that. What do you want to do

Comment: @Ernesto as you see in my post, i want to add multiple persons and those should be inserted on DB separately.

Comment: @Ernesto in the frontend side, there will be add button that adds multiple input fields.

Comment: I think this is what you want
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form

Comment: @Ernesto i don't want to do it on frontend side, I just want to validate it on API side, which is made in Express Js where express-validator is used.