# Django Dynamic Fields Within A Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

A requirement for my app is to give user's capability to create a survey. For each survey, the user should have the capability to add any number of questions. I am trying to achieve this by first defining my models and a form.

```
# models.py.
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Survey(models.Model):
    survey_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.survey_name
```

```
#forms.py
from django import forms

class Survey(forms.Form):
    survey_name = forms.CharField(required=200)
    #TODO: define questions
```

I am stuck. In my form module, how do I define the one to many relationship between the survey and questions in order for the user to add and define questions for each survey they create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial to make dynamic forms [dynamic form using django](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/)
or you can use javascript [dynamic input using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form) to let user creat as many field wish. and get those field on view using `request.POST.getlist("html input field name")` and then insert onto model.